# Why are public enumerated types in an assembly with AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers SecurityCritical?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, security, code-access-security

I get this error in my ASP.Net application:

"*Attempt by security transparent method* `Field.set_FieldType(Constants.DataTypeEnum)` *to access security critical type* `Constants.DataTypeEnum` *failed*."

The security critical type `DataTypeEnum` is a public enumerated type in an assembly which has the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` attribute. (Also `DataTypeEnum` is declared outside of any class or module). It does not have the `SecurityCritical` attribute.

Shouldn't it therefore by default be `SecurityTransparent`? 
Does anyone know why it is `SecurityCritical`?

**Update**

I am trying to dynamically load and run code in a sandbox/remote appdomain.

I am not getting the error now. Tried a number of things. Tried putting enums inside a module. At one point I was getting the error, "*The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference*", for the `Constants` assembly which is used by the sandbox code. I killed the ASP.Net process and deleted the app sub-directory in '*Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Temporary ASP.Net Files*' and now it is working.

If I declare the enums outside a module I now get the error "*Could not load type 'Constants.ReportType' from assembly ...*". If I put them back in a module it works but I am not convinced this is reason for the original error.